# What's wrong with me.htaccess, file? when I open my domain all it does is download a file

Tags: php, .htaccess

My WordPress installation was prompting me to update so I did.

Then I get the message "Your server is running PHP version 5.3.29 but WordPress 5.5.3 requires at least 5.6.20."

So I went into my WAFF and updated my PHP to 7:

[image]

But then I must how done something evil to my .htaccess becaue whenever I go to my domain http://portplays.com/ all it does is download a file...

My .htaccess please advice:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

# WAFF BEGIN
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 days"
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
<FilesMatch "\.(js|css|xml|gz)$">
Header append Vary: Accept-Encoding
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
# WAFF END
```

Comment: Is having `RewriteRule . /index.php [L]` twice a typo here, or real code? Also what file is downloading?

Comment: yea strange I see it

Comment: That whole first block is the same like the one between `# BEGIN WordPress` and `# END WordPress`

Comment: omg this is bad, is there some backup maybe of this file?

Comment: Think you can go here to get default, https://wordpress.org/support/article/htaccess/